# How to retrieve code for .exe file and see how is it build and working?

Tags: python, parsing, progress-bar, 3dsmax

The thing is that there `3dsmaxcmd.exe` which is used for rendering, and which is capable to show how long does it take and estimated time till finish. [image: is capable to show how long does it take and estimated time till finish]

And my goal is to extract that both timedates, or see how is it built and counting progress, to build that kind of tool myself.
By this approach im willing to solve an issue of keeping progress of rendering single frame. Any other approaches and ideas are welcome)

thank you for you attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample code that grabs the timestamps from an image. I broke it up into a few functions that should get you started.

#### To get the window screenshot and all the text using OCR (optical character recognition)

*Note: *I am using a Mac so I haven't tested the get_window_screenshot() on windows.*

```
def get_window_screenshot(window_title):
    if DEBUG:
        im = Image.open('3dsmaxcmd_exe.jpeg')
        return im
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    if system_platform == 'Windows':
        # for windows
        window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle(window_title)
        l, t = window.topleft
        r, b = window.bottomright
    elif system_platform == 'Darwin':
        # for mac
        l, t, w, h = pygetwindow.getWindowGeometry(window_title)
        r = l + w
        b = t + h
    screenshot = screenshot.crop((l, t, r, b))
    return screenshot

def get_window_content(window_screenshot):
    # returns all content in image as a string
    content = pytesseract.image_to_string(window_screenshot)
    return content
```

That gets me: `Current Task: Rendering image... [02:08:05.9] [02:09:37.0 est]`

#### Now to get the timestamps. Here is a way you can do it:

```
def get_timestamps(content):
    t_list = []
    timestamp = _find_timestamp(content)
    while timestamp:
        t_list.append(timestamp[0])
        timestamp = _find_timestamp(content, timestamp[1])
    return t_list

def _find_timestamp(content, start=0):
    timestamp_start = content.find('[', start + 1)
    timestamp_end = content.find(']', start + 1)
    if timestamp_start > 0 and timestamp_end > 0:
        return content[timestamp_start + 1: timestamp_end], timestamp_end
    return False
```

Calling this function gives me: `['02:08:05.9', '02:09:37.0 est']`

Here's the code I used to run:

```
import platform

import pyautogui
import pytesseract
import pygetwindow
from PIL import Image

system_platform = platform.system()

DEBUG = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window_shot = get_window_screenshot("I'm debugging")
    content = get_window_content(window_shot)
    timestamps = get_timestamps(content)
```